# Silex and SecurityServiceProvider

Tags: php, silex

I'm trying to make an autorization for the first time using `Twig` and `SecurityServiceProvider`.

I'm trying to use the code from [documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html):

Registration:

```
$app['security.firewalls'] = array(
'admin' => array(
    'pattern' => '^/admin/',
    'form' => array('login_path' => '/login', 'check_path' => '/admin/login_check'),
    'users' => array(
        'admin' => array('ROLE_ADMIN', '5FZ2Z8QIkA7UTZ4BYkoC+GsReLf569mSKDsfods6LYQ8t+a8EW9oaircfMpmaLbPBh4FOBiiFyLfuZmTSUwzZg=='),
    ),
),
);
```

Controller:

```
$app->get('/login', function(Request $request) use ($app) {
return $app['twig']->render('login.html', array(
    'error'         => $app['security.last_error']($request),
    'last_username' => $app['session']->get('_security.last_username'),
));
});
```

Twig:

```
<form action="{{ path('admin_login_check') }}" method="post">
{{ error }}
<input type="text" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />
<input type="password" name="_password" value="" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And here's an error i get:
**InvalidArgumentException: Identifier "security.last_error" is not defined.**

Why?

Comment: Did you check if there any value first? It might only have a value if there has been an error, but you are echoing it out regardless.

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have in fact registered the Security Service Provider correctly. In the documentation, the complete "security firewalls" example was defined separately as an array without the front register part. Once you have added it in like my codes below, the error should disappear.

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
'security.firewalls' => array(
    'admin' => array(
        'pattern' => '^/admin/',
        'form' => array('login_path' => '/login', 'check_path' => '/admin/login_check'),
        'users' => array(
            'admin' => array('ROLE_ADMIN', '5FZ2Z8QIkA7UTZ4BYkoC+GsReLf569mSKDsfods6LYQ8t+a8EW9oaircfMpmaLbPBh4FOBiiFyLfuZmTSUwzZg=='),
        ),
    )
)
));
```

In addition, please take note that you will need to register two other Service Providers not mentioned in the documentation for the example to work properly.

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SessionServiceProvider());
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\UrlGeneratorServiceProvider());
```